# There is only one structure of ring (with identity) on the abelian group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Prove that a certain ring homomorphism is surjective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is an exercise from the textbook "Algebra: Chapter 0" by Paolo Aluffi.

First, I state necessary facts from the book used in the exercise:

> For every abelian group $G, End_{Ab}(G)$( the set of group homomorphisms from $G$ to $G$) is a ring with operations:
>
> $+: (f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a)$
>
> $.: (fg)(a) = f(g(a))$
>
> and zero $0_{End_{Ab}(G)} = $ trivial map $0: \ \ im0 = 0$, identity $1_{End_{Ab}(G)} = 1_G \in End_{Ab}(G)$
>
> **Proposition.** $End_{Ab}(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ as rings.
>
> Let $R$ be a ring. For $r \in R$, define left-multiplication by $r$ by $\lambda_r$. $\lambda_r$ is an endomorphism of the underlying abelian group $(R,+)$.
>
> **Proposition.** Let $R$ be a ring. Then the function $\lambda: R \to End_{Ab}(R)$ defined by $\lambda(r) = \lambda_r$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

Now, here goes the exercise: it's on the page $138$ in book, numbered $2.16$.

> Prove that there is (up to isomorphism) only one structure of ring(with identity) on the abelian group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Let $R$ be a ring whose underlying group is $\mathbb{Z}$. Then there is an injective ring homomorphism $\lambda: R \to End_{Ab}(R)$, and the latter is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $\lambda$ is surjective is this case.

So, assume $R$ is some ring, whose underlying abelian group is $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. We may denote it as $(\mathbb{Z}, + , o , 1_R = k)$ where $o$ is multiplication in $R$, and $k$ is some integer serving and identity in this ring.

We need to prove that every group homomorphism $\phi:(\mathbb{Z},+) \to (\mathbb{Z},+)$ may be defined by formula $\phi(n) = d \ o \ n$ for some integer $d$.

But every group endomorphism $\phi$ of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is uniquely determined by the image of $1$. Since $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \ \ \phi(n) = \phi(n1) = n\phi(1)$.

And  $1_{(\mathbb{Z},+)}$ is determined as $\forall z \in \mathbb{Z} \ \ 1_{(\mathbb{Z},+)}(z) = k(=1_{(\mathbb{Z},+,o)}) \ o \ z = z$.

What can be done next to show $\lambda: (\mathbb{Z}, +, o, k) \to End_{Ab}(\mathbb{Z})$ is surjective?

Comment: In general, for every unital ring $R$, there is a unique unital ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$.

Comment: @egreg I know, but how does it help? Have you read my post? $(\mathbb{Z}, +, o)$ is some ring with underlying abelian group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$, not necessarily the $\mathbb{Z}$ ring.

Comment: It doesn't matter; you can't define other ring structures on $\mathbb{Z}$ (with the same addition). The ring homomorphism I told about sends $m$ to the $m$-th multiple of the identity. So the only possible identity is $1$ and the rest easily follows.

Comment: @egreg That's what I need to prove! That you can't define other rings structures on $(\mathbb{Z},+)$! And I don't need any proof, I would like the proof in the exercise to be completed first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $(\mathbb{Z},+,\circ,k)$ is a ring structure ($k$ is the identity). Thus $k\circ x=x$, for every $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose $k>0$. Then $k=1+1+\dots+1$, so
$$
x=k\circ x=1\circ x+1\circ x+\dots+1\circ x=k(1\circ x)
$$
In particular, $x\in k\mathbb{Z}$, for every $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $k=1$.

Then for $m>0$ and any $n$,
$$
m\circ n=(1+1+\dots+1)\circ n=1\circ n+1\circ n+\dots+1\circ n=
n+n+\dots+n=mn
$$

If $m<0$, $m\circ n=-((-m)\circ n)=-(-mn)=mn$.

Finish it up, by proving that $k\le0$ is impossible.

Comment: I believe $k = -1$ is possible. The structures are still isomorphic, however.

Comment: @RolandKillian You only get a group homomorphism, but multiplication is not preserved.

Comment: Why wouldn't multiplication be preserved? The multiplication I have in mind is

$$m\circ n := -1\cdot (m\cdot n)$$

The structure would be the exact same as the regular $\mathbb{Z}$. Positive numbers are treated as negative, and vice versa.

The isomorphism would be $\phi(x) := -x$. It is clearly bijective, and preserves both addition and multiplication.

Edit: Pressed enter before finishing comment

Answer (score 2):

$\lambda(k) = \lambda(k \circ k) = \lambda(k)\circ \lambda(k)$ (here the sign on the left is the multiplication in $R$, and the one on the right is functional composition), since we have a ring-homomorphism.

Hence the image of $k$ in $\text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(\Bbb Z)$ is an idempotent endomorphism. Since every endomorphism in $\text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(\Bbb Z)$ is of the form $j \mapsto nj$ for some integer $n$, the fact that the image of $k$ is idempotent means that:

$n^2 = n$, for $\lambda(k) = n\cdot (-)$.

Now $n^2 = n$ is equivalent to: $n(n - 1) = 0$, and since the integers are an integral domain, we have only two choices: $n = 0$, or $n = 1$.

The former case leads to $\lambda$ being the $0$-map, which is certainly *not* injective. So we must have $n = 1$, which establishes the surjectivity of $\lambda$.

Comment: You need to still "fill in the gaps" by showing that for $r \in R$ that $\lambda(r) = \lambda(k) +\cdots + \lambda(k)$ (for $r$ summands), using the fact that $\lambda$ preserves addition.

Comment: So, you proved that $\lambda(k)(1) = 1$. Hence, $\lambda(k) = 1_{\mathbb{Z}}$. But that's have been already known since $\lambda$ is a ring homomorphism, so it sends $1_{(\mathbb{Z}, +, o)}$ to the identity mapping on $G$. How surjecctivity follows from it? Am I missing something?

Comment: As an abelian group, $\Bbb Z = \langle 1 \rangle$ (it is cyclic). So if a group homomorphism (which a ring-homomorphism certainly is) maps into $\Bbb Z$ and $1$ is in the image, it is surjective.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Where do you see a ring homomorphism with a codomain $\mathbb{Z}$? We have $\lambda: (\mathbb{Z}, +, o, k = $identity of the ring ) $\to End_{Ab}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Your first proposition says that $\text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(\Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z$ as rings, under the map $(j \mapsto nj) \mapsto n$. Thus post-composition of $\lambda$ with this isomorphism yields a surjective homomorphism into $\Bbb Z$ (in other words, $\text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(\Bbb Z) $ is generated *as an abelian group* by the identity automorphism).

Comment: How do you know you still have an integral domain with the alternative ring structure?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(k)=a$. Then $\phi(k)=a\circ k$. Hence if $\phi(x)=d\circ x$, then $d=a$. This restricts our search.

**1.** Let's prove that $k=1$ or $k=-1$.

*1.1.* $k$ can not be $0$: $1\circ 0=0\neq1$.

*1.2.* If $k>0$, then $1=1\circ k=1\circ(1+...+1)=1\circ1+...+1\circ1$ ($k$ times).

Thus $k$ must be $1$.

*1.3.* If $k<0$, then $1=1\circ k=1\circ(-1-...-1)=1\circ(-1)+...+1\circ(-1)$ ($-k$ times).

Thus $k$ must be $-1$.

**2.** Let us now prove that $\phi(x)=a\circ x$.

*2.1.* $\phi(0)=0=a\circ0$.

*2.2.1.* $x>0$ and $k=1$.

$\phi(x)=\phi(1+...+1)=\phi(k+...+k)=\phi(k)+...+\phi(k)=a+...+a$.

$\phi(x)=a\circ1+...+a\circ1=a\circ(1+...+1)=a\circ x$.

*2.2.2.* $x>0$ and $k=-1$.

$\phi(x)=\phi(1+...+1)=\phi(-k-...-k)=-\phi(k)-...-\phi(k)=-a-...-a$.

But $-a=a\circ(-k)=a\circ1$ (Aluffi, page 120) and we have the same:

$\phi(x)=a\circ1+...+a\circ1=a\circ(1+...+1)=a\circ x$.

*2.3.1.* $x<0$ and $k=1$.

$\phi(x)=\phi(-1-...-1)=\phi(-k-...-k)=-\phi(k)-...-\phi(k)=-a-...-a$.

$\phi(x)=a\circ(-1)+...+a\circ(-1)=a\circ(-1-...-1)=a\circ x$.

*2.3.2.* $x<0$ and $k=-1$.

$\phi(x)=\phi(-1-...-1)=\phi(k+...+k)=\phi(k)+...+\phi(k)=a+...+a$.

$\phi(x)=a\circ(-1)+...+a\circ(-1)=a\circ(-1-...-1)=a\circ x$.

$3.$ Thus the embedding $(\Bbb Z,+,\circ,k)\rightarrow\text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(\Bbb Z,+)$ s.t. $r\mapsto(x\mapsto r\circ x)$ is surjective.

This gives $(\Bbb Z,+,\circ,k)\cong$ $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are various alternatives to prove the result, here will merely complete the proof in the book by showing $\lambda$ is surjective.

Suppose $1_R=k$  and $f\in\mathrm{End}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(R)$. We have
$$
f(n)=f(n)\circ 1_R=(n[f(1)])\circ (k[1])\\
=nk[f(1)\circ 1]=(k[f(1)])\circ (n[1])=f(k)\circ n=\lambda_{f(1_R)}(n)
$$

The notation $a[b]$ for $a\in \mathbb Z_{>0}$ is used to denote $\underbrace{b+\cdots+b}_{a \text{ times}}$ for simplicity.

Now it is clear that now $f=\lambda_{f(1_R)}$ and hence $\lambda$ is surjective.